# Why can't I insert a map into a vector at a new element?

Tags: c++, graph, vector, maps, dijkstra

I have a `vector` of `maps` which I'm using to store a node (the vector index), the node it's going to (map->second), and the cost (map->first). It will be used for graphing.  I am unable to write a function which will allow me to insert a new node with the node it's going to with a cost.

Example:

```
vector[first_node].insert(make_pair(cost, second_node);
```

Using the above method, if there is an existing node at location `[first_node]` in the vector, it's going to add to that map instead of creating an entirely new point. I've tried using `push_back`, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Typical error:

```
error C2664: 'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(std::map<_Kty,double> &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty> &&'

for line: `edges.push_back(make_pair(second, cost));`
```

Relevant code for the whole function:

```
template <typename T>
void Graph<T>::map_edges(T first, T second, double cost) {
  edges.resize(nodes.size()); //Resize the edges vector to make room for the new insertion. The new node already exists in a set of nodes called 'nodes'.
  // Loop through the existing set of nodes...
  for (set<T>::iterator node_it = nodes.begin();
    node_it != nodes.end(); node_it++) {
    //Check if the first node exists already.
    if (first == *node_it) {
      set<T>::iterator node_begin = nodes.begin();
      set<T>::iterator node_pos = nodes.find(first);
      int pos = distance(node_begin, node_pos);
      //Then assign it's numerical value to the vector slot, and add the 
      //second and third words as a pair associated with that slot.
      edges[pos].insert(make_pair(second, cost));
      // edges.push_back(map<double, T>()); //This is where I would rather insert at a new location.
      break;
    }
  } 
}
```

Definition of edges:

```
vector<map<T, double> > edges;
```

Comment: " if there is an existing node at location [first_node] in the vector it's going to add to that map, instead of create an entirely new point". If there is no existing node at `first_node`, then you are accessing beyond the bounds of the vector and you get undefined behaviour.

Comment: Please post the definition of `edges`. I suspect it is `std::vector<std::map<?, double>>`.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. `std::vector` can't have two elements with the same index. It makes no sense.

Comment: You said: I've got a vector of maps that I'm using to store a node (the vector index), the node it's going to (map->second) and the cost(map->first). It's for a graph. This what I am thinking std::vector<std::map<size_t,double> >. Please, can you add the declaration of your vector?

Comment: @juanchopanza: I've resized the vector to make room for it. There should be room. @hmjd: done. @aleguna: I'm storing a map at each vector point. So at `vector[first]`, you would have a `map<double,T>`, thus storing two elements.

Comment: @ChrisPaton in that case, there is always an existing node there.

Comment: Just use `map.clear()` before insertion to achieve same effect as a new map.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yeah, but it's accessing that particular one that I'm not sure how to do without affecting others.

Comment: this line is wrong // edges.push_back(map<double, T>()); it doesn't match with the declaration of edges vector<map<T, double> > edges. The types are swapped.

Comment: Cheers @AlessandroTeruzzi. That's compiling now. Damn typos! :)